# Where is `~/.R/snippets/r.snippets` on Windows 10?

Tags: r

The "Saving and Sharing Snippets" section of this RStudio article (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets) says snippets are saved in `~/.R/snippets/r.snippets`. Where is this on a Windows 10 installation? I tried opening `cmd` and then `cd ~/.R/snippets/` but this directory is not found. I also tried searching for `snippets` via Windows search and found no such directory.

Comment: On windows, for some reason it may consider `HOME` to be `/Users/username/Documents/`, you might check under there.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you, that was it. For posterity: I am using Windows 10 and the path for me is: `C:\Users\<yourUserName>\Documents\.R\snippets`

Comment: You can change this if you want to use `/Users/username` instead: do a windows search (`Win` key) for "env" and you should see "edit environment variables"; click on the *Environment Variables...* button and find `HOME`, most likely under "User variables for <username>". (If not found ... create one.)